# How to get multiple versions from one specific row and column in HBase

Tags: hbase

As we know, hbase has a feature that a specific Row and specific Column can record recent change values by timestamps.
So my question is, HOW TO list all the changed values using any HBase command? I googled a lot, but didn't find any useful links.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the number of version you get for Scan and Get and it will retrieve them:

```
 HTable tbl = new HTable(tableName);
 Get q= new Get(Bytes.toBytes(key));
 q.setMaxVersions(numberOfVersionsYouWant);
 Result row= tbl.get(q);
 NavigableMap<byte[],NavigableMap<byte[],NavigableMap<Long,byte[]>>> allVersions=row.getMap();
```

Answer (score 15):

Versioning is not enabled by default. So you have specify it while creating table.

```
create 'student',{NAME=>"personal",Versions=>5},'school'
```

Here versioning is enabled for column "personal" but not for column 'school'

This can be seen if you describe table

```
hbase(main):009:0> describe 'student'
Table student is ENABLED
student
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'personal', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '5', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
{NAME => 'school', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

For `personal` it shows `VERSIONS => '5'` For `school` it shows `VERSIONS => '1'`.

If table is already created it can be altered

```
alter 'student',NAME=>'school',VERSIONS =>3

hbase(main):011:0> describe 'student'
Table student is ENABLED
student
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'personal', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '5', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
{NAME => 'school', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

Not it shows `VERSIONS => '3'` For `school` as expected.

Put data into table. Enter multiple times in same cell. And then scan the table.

```
put 'student','1','personal:name','kaushik'
put 'student','1','personal:name','kaushik_again'
put 'student','1','school:name','great_school'
put 'student','1','school:name','great_school_again'

scan 'student',{VERSIONS=>10}
ROW  COLUMN+CELL
 1   column=personal:name, timestamp=1443002303208, value=kaushik_again
 1   column=personal:name, timestamp=1443002294049, value=kaushik
 1   column=school:name, timestamp=1443002320753, value=great_school_again
 1   column=school:name, timestamp=1443002311421, value=great_school
```

As expected it is showing old value as well as new value.

Answer (score 12):

The same can be achieved in hbase shell using:

```
get 'tablename', 'rowid', {COLUMN => 'cf:info', VERSIONS => 3}
```

The above will show the max 3 versions of the cell, if available.

Comment: Is there a way to get min 3 versions?