# In HBase shell,how to scan the latest 5 data in a row?

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

My HBase table  name is  "recommend",I have inserted into 5 rows data.

Just like

`put 'recommend','1','info:itemId',"1:1"

 put 'recommend','1','info:itemId',"1:2"

 put 'recommend','1','info:itemId',"1:3"

 put 'recommend','1','info:itemId',"1:4"
 put 'recommend','1','info:itemId',"1:5"`

When I use  `get 'recommend','1', {COLUMN => 'info:itemId', VERSIONS => 5}`
 ,the result is not the latest 5 data from row 1 ! It's only one! Who can tell me what is problem or give me some tips?
[image]

Comment: In your `CREATE TABLE` command, did you specify the number of `VERSIONS` to store? or alternately, the `TTL` (time to live) for each version before deletiion?

Comment: Try the `describe` command to know which settings are used. Cf. https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/ for a quick recap of the shell commands (and basic CREATE options)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can find right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466079/how-to-get-multiple-versions-from-one-specific-row-and-column-in-hbase). 
Probably you didn't specify versions number when created table. Default value is 1.